# Macro runs on PC but not on MacOS: Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, macos

I can get this code to run on PC but not on Mac. The code allows you to select text files and convert them into worksheets and append them to your current workbook.

```
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilesToOpen(x))
```

The above line of code is sending the program to the Error Handler and causing a subscript out of range error.

In the link below is a picture of the Locals Window that shows the path name from the file I wish to grab.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePgA3.jpg

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()

Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sDelimiter As String
Dim answer As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

answer = MsgBox("Before moving forward, all other workbooks must be closed" _
& vbCrLf & "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If answer = vbYes Then 'do nothing
Else: Exit Sub
End If

sDelimiter = ","

#If Mac Then
FilesToOpen = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
#Else
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the CDR Text Files to Open")
#End If


If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

x = 1
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilesToOpen(x))
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
wkbTemp.Close (False)
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
  Other:=True, OtherChar:=","
x = x + 1

While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilesToOpen(x))
    With wkbAll
        wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
    End With
    x = x + 1
Wend

wkbAll.Sheets.Copy After:=Workbooks(2).Sheets(Workbooks(2).Worksheets.Count)
wkbAll.Close False
    
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler


End Sub

Function Select_File_Or_Files_Mac() As String()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyScript As String
Dim MyFiles As String
Dim MySplit As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim FName As String
Dim mybook As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
MyPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
'Or use MyPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:Ron:Desktop:TestFolder:"

' In the following statement, change true to false in the line "multiple
' selections allowed true" if you do not want to be able to select more
' than one file. Additionally, if you want to filter for multiple files, change
' {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls""} to
' {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text""}
' if you want to filter on xls and csv files, for example.
MyScript = _
"set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
           "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
         " {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text"", ""public.text""} " & _
           "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
           MyPath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
           "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
           "return theFiles"

MyFiles = MacScript(MyScript)
Dim returnList() As String
On Error GoTo 0

If MyFiles <> "" Then
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'MsgBox MyFiles
    MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")
    ReDim returnList(LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit))
    For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

        returnList(N) = MySplit(N)

    Next N
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Select_File_Or_Files_Mac = returnList
Else
    ReDim returnList(0 To 0)
    returnList(0) = "False"
    Select_File_Or_Files_Mac = returnList
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `Application.GetOpenFilename` and `Select_File_Or_Files_Mac` return an array of one or more file names, but the first array is one-based, and your Mac version is *zero-based*.

Your counter `x` *starts* at 1, so it's already out of range for a "mac" array with only one file: i.e. `FilesToOpen(0)`

You can modify your Mac code to return a one-based array.

Modify this part:

```vb
MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")

ReDim returnList(1 to To UBound(MySplit)+1) 'one-based not zero-based...

For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)
    returnList(N + 1) = MySplit(N)
Next N
```

...and this part:

```vb
ReDim returnList(1 To 1)
returnList(1) = "False"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think I would've ever realized this. I am now getting a file not found error message. Going to try to figure this out now.