# I want to use vba to insert photo into cell in excel for macbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos, macbookpro-touch-bar

I want to use vba (macro) to insert a photo into a cell on the MacBook, but it is used well in Windows Excel, but it is not used in the MacBook. Is it because the path to load the photo file is different? Can I modify this vba to be usable on macbook?
I'm getting an execution error in the bolded part of the code below.

```
Sub insert_Pic()


Dim Pic As Variant


***Pic = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Picture Files,*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tif;*.gif;*.png")***


If Pic = False Then Exit Sub


With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Pic).ShapeRange


.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse


.Height = Selection.Height - 4


.Width = Selection.Width - 4


.Left = Selection.Left + 2


.Top = Selection.Top + 2


End With


End Sub
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-make-getopenfilename-to-work-on-a-mac/7b6b1854-b979-4d53-a5f3-f88b02201b61 or https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/selectfiles/index.html

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I couldn't find how to change the code in this bold font. Do I have to rewrite the code entirely instead of just changing this part?

Comment: You'd need to pull out the relevant parts into a function you could use instead of getOpenFileName.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297822/macro-runs-on-pc-but-not-on-macos-subscript-out-of-range-error and the function `Select_File_Or_Files_Mac` in that code.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking. Since this is the first time using this vba, it is because I do not understand how vba works.
Would it be possible to run it if I change it to the following sentence?      #If Mac Then
FilesToOpen = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
#Else
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Picture Files,*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tif;*.gif;*.png", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the CDR Text Files to Open")
#End If

Comment: Something like that should work, yes, but I don't have a Mac to test.

Comment: Sub insert_Pic()
Dim Pic As Variant
#If Mac Then
FilesToOpen = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
#Else
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Picture Files,*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tif;*.gif;*.png", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the CDR Text Files to Open")
#End If
If Pic = False Then Exit Sub
With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Pic).ShapeRange
.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
.Height = Selection.Height - 4
.Width = Selection.Width - 4
.Left = Selection.Left + 2
.Top = Selection.Top + 2
End With
End Sub

Comment: When I tested it on my Mac, I got a compile error saying "Sub or Function is not defined". Did I insert the sentence wrong?

Comment: If you need to add code, you can edit your question and add it there.  Code in comments is not really readable...   If you're getting a compile error then it should highlight the problem part of your code - you need to let us know what that is...

Comment: Thank you so much and I'm sorry. I can't understand your answer because I have no idea how vba works. Could you please give me some code that I can change or use? If it's not possible I guess I'll have to ditch this vba and find a new way to easily insert pictures :(